# TOMCAT 7, Clean, Clean workdirectory

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

when I clean TOMCAT or I clean thé tomcat work directory I lose all file saved in Tomcat folder,
Can I disable this option ?

Comment: what would you expect to happen if you clean the tomcat work directory? why do you clean the tomcat directory if you don't want it to be cleared? Perhaps your question is not as clear as it could be

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the tomcat working directory will erase all the projects deploy into Tomcat. If you do not want this to happen , simply do not clean it.

If you want to start off with a new build every time , use Maven for managing your project and deploy your project with `mvn clean install tomcat7:deploy` . The clean goal of maven cleans your container before building.